# How to make a Python module available to all users

Tags: linux, rhel, amazon-linux

We have a script that installs AWS CLI into Amazon Linux 2 (really many different distros, but AL2 is what I'm working with). It seems like mostly all of the components get installed, but not all of them stick when capturing an image and then deploying it to AWS Workspaces.

How do we potentially get all of the modules available for all users, even domain users, after it gets deployed?

Here are some pictures of what the script does.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the error that happens when we deploy the image to AWS Workspaces with a domain user.

[image]

Comment: Posting the install script and how you are running it would be much more helpful than the images.  It appears you are installing many packages using `pip` but only for the root user.  You should be using `pip` to install those packages into a Python virtual environment that is available to all users.  Not recommended, but you could even use `pip` to install those packages in the global environment.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Here is the install script.

I have a feeling we might be better of just having users install it after-the-fact, even though we wanted to make it easy for them and available right away.

https://pastebin.com/GfQZJfKt

Comment: Also, as a note as I forgot to mention it, we do run this script as sudo. Even running without sudo, it doesn't make a difference in the behavior.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy and paste the text.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have your installed Python modules installed globally and your script is not doing that.  In fact, your script is explicitly telling `pip` to only install modules for the user running the script:

`python3 -m pip install --user boto3`

If you are running the script as the `root` user or using `sudo`, then these modules only get installed for the `root` user and would not be accessible to anyone else on the system.

Later on, your script runs:

`python3 -m pipx install aws-sso-util`

which, by my reading of what `pipx` is, installs `aws-sso-util` into an isolated environment.  This better explains the final error you receive: while `/usr/local/bin/awssso` is available globally from `pipx`, you installed the `boto3` module only for the `root` user.  If your script was run without `sudo` by any user besides `root`, `awssso` would likely work correctly for the user running the script.

One way to get global Python modules, would be to create a new virtual environment in a global place using `sudo` or the `root` user:

`sudo python3 -m venv /opt/aws-venv`

activate the environment for the remainder of this user session:

`source /opt/aws-venv/bin/activate`

install the packages you need into the virtual environment:

`sudo /opt/aws-venv/bin/pip install lxml defusedxml boto3 botocore boto inquirerpy python-dateutil ensurepath aws-sso-util`

This new virtual environment should be available to all users and can be activated with `source /opt/aws-venv/bin/activate`

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I am going to test this out tomorrow. I am out of the office currently so I can't test just yet.